# Only One Collapseable List Open at a Time

Tags: javascript, html

I have a collapsable list below, and I want it so that there can only be one list open at a time. (There's a lot of extra CSS in there)

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;
}

body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 10px;
 color: #999;
}

form {
 margin: 40px 0;
}

div {
 clear: both;
 margin: 0 50px;
}

label {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #D1D3D4
}

/* hide input */
input.radio:empty {
 margin-left: -999px;
}

/* style label */
input.radio:empty ~ label {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 line-height: 2.5em;
 text-indent: 3.25em;
 margin-top: 2em;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}

input.radio:empty ~ label:before {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 content: '';
 width: 2.5em;
 background: #D1D3D4;
 border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* toggle hover */
input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label:before {
 content:'\2714';
 text-indent: .9em;
 color: #C2C2C2;
}

input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label {
 color: #888;
}

/* toggle on */
input.radio:checked ~ label:before {
 content:'\2714';
 text-indent: .9em;
 color: #9CE2AE;
 background-color: #4DCB6D;
}

input.radio:checked ~ label {
 color: #777;
}
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;
}

body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 10px;
 color: #999;
}

form {
 margin: 40px 0;
}

div {
 clear: both;
 margin: 0 50px;
}

label {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #D1D3D4
}

/* hide input */
input.radio:empty {
 margin-left: -999px;
}

/* style label */
input.radio:empty ~ label {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 line-height: 2.5em;
 text-indent: 3.25em;
 margin-top: 2em;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}

input.radio:empty ~ label:before {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 content: '';
 width: 2.5em;
 background: #D1D3D4;
 border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* toggle hover */
input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label:before {
 content:'\2714';
 text-indent: .9em;
 color: #C2C2C2;
}

input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label {
 color: #888;
}

/* toggle on */
input.radio:checked ~ label:before {
 content:'\2714';
 text-indent: .9em;
 color: #9CE2AE;
 background-color: #4DCB6D;
}

input.radio:checked ~ label {
 color: #777;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Foundation Bolting</button>
<div class="panel">

    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1-1" class="radio">
      <label for="radio1-1">Foundation Bolts</label>
    </div>
    
     <div>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1-2" class="radio">
      <label for="radio1-2">Foundation Plates</label>
    </div>
    
    
</div>

<button class="accordion">Wall Bracing</button>
<div class="panel">

  <div>
      <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2-1" class="radio">
      <label for="radio2-1">Strong Tie Retrofit Connectors</label>
    </div>

     <div>
      <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2-2" class="radio">
      <label for="radio2-2">Angled Iron Struts</label>
    </div>

</div>
```

For example, if I click on Foundation Bolting, then click on  Wall Bracing, Foundation Bolting will close. I've spent a lot of time searching this up, but all the other ones I find don't work because I don't have a list. How can I fix this?

(P.S. I don't want to add in a list because then I'll have random dots around that I don't want)

Comment: write something to collapseAll whenever a list is clicked before opening that one list. add something to check if the same list was clicked (if so don't do anything)

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331 how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code a little bit and added a function called `closeAccordions`.

It checks of the `accordion` is already open.
If it isn't, close the rest first, because we're now opening it.
If it is, just toggle the current one.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {     
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        if(!this.classList.contains("active")) {
            closeAccordions();
        }
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}

function closeAccordions() {
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].classList.remove("active");
        acc[i].nextElementSibling.classList.remove("show");

    }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;
}

body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 10px;
 color: #999;
}

form {
 margin: 40px 0;
}

div {
 clear: both;
 margin: 0 50px;
}

label {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #D1D3D4
}

/* hide input */
input.radio:empty {
 margin-left: -999px;
}

/* style label */
input.radio:empty ~ label {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 line-height: 2.5em;
 text-indent: 3.25em;
 margin-top: 2em;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}

input.radio:empty ~ label:before {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 content: '';
 width: 2.5em;
 background: #D1D3D4;
 border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* toggle hover */
input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label:before {
 content:'\2714';
 text-indent: .9em;
 color: #C2C2C2;
}

input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label {
 color: #888;
}

/* toggle on */
input.radio:checked ~ label:before {
 content:'\2714';
 text-indent: .9em;
 color: #9CE2AE;
 background-color: #4DCB6D;
}

input.radio:checked ~ label {
 color: #777;
}
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;
}

body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 10px;
 color: #999;
}

form {
 margin: 40px 0;
}

div {
 clear: both;
 margin: 0 50px;
}

label {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #D1D3D4
}

/* hide input */
input.radio:empty {
 margin-left: -999px;
}

/* style label */
input.radio:empty ~ label {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 line-height: 2.5em;
 text-indent: 3.25em;
 margin-top: 2em;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}

input.radio:empty ~ label:before {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 content: '';
 width: 2.5em;
 background: #D1D3D4;
 border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* toggle hover */
input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label:before {
 content:'\2714';
 text-indent: .9em;
 color: #C2C2C2;
}

input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label {
 color: #888;
}

/* toggle on */
input.radio:checked ~ label:before {
 content:'\2714';
 text-indent: .9em;
 color: #9CE2AE;
 background-color: #4DCB6D;
}

input.radio:checked ~ label {
 color: #777;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Foundation Bolting</button>
<div class="panel">

    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1-1" class="radio">
      <label for="radio1-1">Foundation Bolts</label>
    </div>
    
     <div>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1-2" class="radio">
      <label for="radio1-2">Foundation Plates</label>
    </div>
    
    
</div>

<button class="accordion">Wall Bracing</button>
<div class="panel">

  <div>
      <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2-1" class="radio">
      <label for="radio2-1">Strong Tie Retrofit Connectors</label>
    </div>

     <div>
      <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2-2" class="radio">
      <label for="radio2-2">Angled Iron Struts</label>
    </div>

</div>
```